# a comma between day of week and day of month

Tags: punctuation, commas, dates

Should I use a comma writing a date in the format of day of week and day of month only? The month is known from the context, so the date is, for example, "Thursday, 7"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not put a comma after Thursday. You should write it as "Thursday the seventh". This is the correct format, as you should also type out numbers from 0-10.

Comment: I'm using a number for the day of month in a mobile app to conserve space. Does this make any punctuational difference?
E.g. is "Thursday 15" correct?

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly acceptable. That is what Apple does in their MacBook's header when displaying the day and date.